# Does a DirectoryInfo instance still work on a different PC?

Tags: c#, serialization, directoryinfo

If you send a DirectoryInfo instance from PC1 to PC2, is GetFiles or GetDirectories still working?

```
public void DirTest()
    {
        //On first PC:

        DirectoryInfo driveC = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\randomdir\");

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ns = new MemoryStream();

        bf.Serialize(ns, driveC);
        SendStream(ns); //Sending the stream to the second PC


        //On second PC:


        ns = ReceiveStream(); //Receiving the stream from the first PC
        ns.Position = 0;
        DirectoryInfo di = (DirectoryInfo)bf.Deserialize(ns);

        //Does this work?
        foreach (FileInfo item in di.GetFiles())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

If you execute that code on the same PC it works but i dont have the enviroment to test if this works on 2 different pcs.

Maybe the SubDirectories and Files are saved in an array in the directoryinfo class because i found this serialization function:
[image: Serialization function in DirectoryInfo]

Comment: You want to end up with the information from PC1 or PC2? And what exactly are you concerned about? The serialization or retrieving information?

Comment: I think you're on dangerous ground trying to serialise classes you don't know are safe to be used in that way and may not even have constructors that allow you to serialise properly. Why not create your own class with the properties you actually need and send them over the wire instead? Of course it's still odd how you expect a `DirectoryInfo` to be useful on another machine unless it's a network drive.

Comment: Patrick Hofman I want to know If a DirectoryInfo instance from PC1 is still woking on PC2. And if GetDirectories() still returns the directories of PC1

Comment: @DavidG `DirectoryInfo` is specifically marked `Serializable`, so it is safe to use it that way, however it does not operate like the OP expects.

Comment: @RonBeyer Your definition of "safe" is different to mine, especially when the only field that actually matters is the directory path.

Comment: @DavidG Personally I don't see why the `DirectoryInfo` object *should be* serializable, but if you know what the limitations are, and how to use it properly, I can't see it being unsafe as it has no side effects (it doesn't create the directory, you can call `DirectoryInfo.Exists` to see if it is there, etc).

Comment: @RonBeyer The moment you need to dig into reference source to check if something is safe to do when you only need to send over a string, you need to ask yourself *why*. So kudos to your answer, but it's really daft to even contemplate in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it only works if you have the same directory name on both machines. Let's take a look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,30fa608717e5ce8e)...

First, `DirectoryInfo` inherits `FileSystemInfo`, so when you deserialize `DirectoryInfo`, this constructor is called:

```
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    private DirectoryInfo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        Directory.CheckPermissions(string.Empty, FullPath, checkHost: false);
        DisplayPath = GetDisplayName(OriginalPath, FullPath);
    }
```

Where `base` is a `FileSystemInfo`, and this constructor is used:

```
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.Machine)]
    protected FileSystemInfo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        // Must use V1 field names here, since V1 didn't implement 
        // ISerializable.
        FullPath = Path.GetFullPathInternal(info.GetString("FullPath"));
        OriginalPath = info.GetString("OriginalPath");

        // Lazily initialize the file attributes.
        _dataInitialised = -1;
    }
```

So you can see that the only thing that is serialized isis the `FullPath` and `OriginalPath` values. The data inside the directory is not serialized and if you call `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` you will enumerate the files in the local computer, not the computer that serialized the `DirectoryInfo` in the first place. In fact the source specifically says `Lazily initialize the file attributes`, which means that they are loaded when requested.

```
    // Returns an array of Files in the DirectoryInfo specified by path
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    public FileInfo[] GetFiles()
    {
        return InternalGetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    }
```

Which calls:

```
    // Returns an array of Files in the current DirectoryInfo matching the 
    // given search criteria (ie, "*.txt").
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    private FileInfo[] InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        Contract.Requires(searchPattern != null);
        Contract.Requires(searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories || searchOption == SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        IEnumerable<FileInfo> enble = FileSystemEnumerableFactory.CreateFileInfoIterator(FullPath, OriginalPath, searchPattern, searchOption);
        List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>(enble);
        return fileList.ToArray();
    }
```

And again, you see that nothing is used from the serialized information.